# Derivatives API/Viewer fails with some models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We are transforming all of our models using the derivatives API - and after downloading all assets for offline use (we must support offline users), two things happens:

1. The viewer crashes (the model disappears) when rotation/zooming the model
2. Some of the texture files are empty (0 bytes)

The first issue also happens on https://viewer.autodesk.com/, you can play with it in the following link:

https://viewer.autodesk.com/id/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90MTUzMjUwMzMxOTc4OF8wOTAyMDU4OTE5MjU1OTc0N18xNTMyNTAzMzE5Nzg4Lm53ZA?=&designtype=nwd&sheetId=NTMyMTY1ZDAtNTFlZS00OTNlLTk1NDItMmIzMjM3NjRjYmFh

This is a Navisworks model can be found in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SPjsrOTDHucX35HHqaa_EbkQ5mytC_cu/view?usp=sharing))

What can cause these issues?

Thanks,

Amir

Comment: Does "Some of the texture files are empty (0 bytes)" mean that Viewer failed to texture files (HTTP Error 404) while loading? In addition, may I know what's your test environment and which Viewer version you used when viewing this model?

Comment: @EasonKang I'm sorry, these are 404 that we are getting when trying to download some textures. The errors that we are getting are `Texture load error`s - but it's not the first time, and as far as we know the viewer should also work without them. When the model disappears, however, there's no exception thrown.. This happens with Viewer V4.2

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I will do some tests on your model when I’m back to work. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Hi @EasonKang, any news regarding the tests with our model? We're still experiencing the problem.

Comment: @AmirBerman My apologies, I have serval whole day customer meetings in these two days. I tested your model on Viewer v4.2 and higher. I found that it could be reproduced at my end. Some materials are failed to download and Viewer will hang on every orbiting. So, I'm inquiring with our engineering team for insights, please bear with me again, will get back to you once I got their replies. Thanks

Comment: @AmirBerman I found your NWD is a combination of many RVTs and one DWG. Is that DWG from Advance Steel? Besides, is there any custom material with your owned texture images in the RVTs converted into NWC?